# ListView in page without messing up scrolling

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
--- Stack Layout / Relative Layout--- 
- some widget (e.g. Label)          -
- some widget (e.g. Label)          -
- ListView                          -
-------------------------------------
```

However, I also want the following scroll behaviour:
Top widgets disappear first then ListView starts scrolling. Basically, I want a "natural" scrolling behaviour.

One way I can achieve this is by making the whole page a ListView and putting the widgets as a Header for the ListView

But that has one problem... which I think is a bug in Xamarin.Forms:

If you have a long Label (what else to hold text?), it will not display all of it. It will actually make it scrollable and display only part of it at a time. What makes this even worse is that you cannot scroll the Label "easily", you have to try multiple times to make it scroll the label instead of the page, it's obviously bugged. That happens even if the page itself has hit the end (i.e. can't scroll any more), the Label still can't be scrolled easily.

Is there another way or a workaround to achieve what I want?

Comment: I'd stick with the header idea and on the listview set hasunevenrows = true and hardcode your label heights to be big enough to display the whole label. Scrollviews within scrollviews can have weird behaviours and I usually avoid them.

Comment: but how would I know the required height for the text? I'm thinking maybe I can calculate that based on the text, or maybe there is a better way after rendering (say by setting a short timer or a render trigger).

Comment: it might work if you just set hasunevenrows to true. alternative would be forget the list view and create a stacklayout inside a scrollview instead. This might make things more difficult when you're determining what's selected but idk what you're trying to do with this

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comments suggests, the best is to set the HeightRequest of the Label to the needed value. 
Here is how I measure the height of the text on Android (you'll need DependencyService, if you want to call this function from Xamarin.Forms):

```
double measureString(string text, string font, double fontSize, double width)
    {
        var textView = new TextView(global::Android.App.Application.Context);
        textView.Typeface = Android.Graphics.Typeface.Create(font, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        textView.SetText(text, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        textView.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Px, (float)(fontSize * Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.ScaledDensity));
        int widthMeasureSpec = Android.Views.View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec((int)(width * Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density), width == 0 ? Android.Views.MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified : Android.Views.MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
        int heightMeasureSpec = Android.Views.View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, Android.Views.MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified);
        textView.Measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        textView.SetIncludeFontPadding(false);
        return (width == 0 ? textView.MeasuredWidth : textView.MeasuredHeight) / Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
    }
```

Comment: this is the code I didn't even know I wanted. It's beautiful.

Comment: thanks! I'm not sure how I didn't reply to this, I think i didn't notice it. Do you know how would I get the font name that Xamarin is using?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms's default is an empty string. On Android I think it is substituted with Roboto, on iOS - Helvetica